# Allocating 2D dynamic arrays (with long long int)

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

```
    long long int ** A = new long long int * [N];
    for ( long long int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {A[i]=new long long int[N];}
```

why does this lead to this warning:
warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from '__int64' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data

Is it not possible to have a long long int 2d dynamic array?

Comment: What is the type of N?

Comment: You want to have 2^64 * 2^ 64; that is an array with 2^128 elements. I doubt the whole world has enough memory to hold your array.

Comment: @Marius Bancila: How can you say how many elements are there without knowing the value of `N`?

Answer (score 4):

The warning you are getting has absolutely nothing to do with the fact that your array consists of `long long` elements. The warning is issued either for your `i` variable or for your `N`. Most likely it is `N` that's causing the problem. What is `N`? How is it declared? I suspect it is also a `long long`.

In C++ language the type that is used for specifying memory sizes (and, incidentally, array sizes and indices) is called `size_t`. Apparently on your platform `size_t` is synonymous with 32-bit `unsigned int` type (32 bit platform?). The compiler is trying to convert your `N`, which is apparently a 64-bit type, to `size_t` and that triggers the warning.

In any case, there's absolutely no reason to insist on using `long long` for `i` or for `N`. Choose a more reasonable type for both (or convert `N` to that type) and the warning will disappear.

Comment: Is it possible to change size_t

Comment: @Ezz: Change `size_t`? No, it is a standard type. But why? For what purpose? What you really have to do is change the declarations of your `i` and your `N`. There's absolutely no point in declaring them as `long long`. In fact, it might be a good idea to declare them as `size_t`. That will fix your warning.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  #include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int N=10;
        int i;
        long long int **A=new long long int*[N];
        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
                A[i]=new long long int [N];
        }
        A[2][5]=5;
        cout<<A[2][5]<<endl;
        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
                delete []A[i];
        delete [] A;
        return 0;
}
```

works for me 
no warning even with -Wall

Comment: may I know the reason for downvote
I use a constant for N but can be a dynamic value as well
and this code will run properly unless and untill you overrun allowed array size for two dimetional array